# CSS floating controls but with last under previous in small browser window

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-float

I'm working on placing three select controls on a web page which are in a horizontal row when the browser window permits.  On smaller windows the third control should be directly below the second.
Below is the closest I've managed to get:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<select class="selector float-left">
    <option>One</option>
</select>
<select class="selector float-left">
    <option>Two</option>
</select>
<select class="selector float-right">
    <option>Three</option>
</select>
```

with the associated styling

```
.wrapper {
max-width:470px;
min-width:400px;
}

.selector {
width: 150px;
margin-left: 5px;
}

.float-left {
float: left;
}

.float-right {
float: right;
}
```

Here it is as a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BBgriff/Fpsn7/1/) that is the closest I've managed to get but the final control floats too far to the right.  I've tried several combinations of floats and containers, but can't seem to work out the right one.  It seems to me that the third div should be float-left, but then it appears underneath the first div when the window size is reduced.

Comment: have you think about using `@media` for specific viewports, coz for that you can manage it swiftly.

Comment: plus one for clear code examples, what you expect and a jsfiddle.

Comment: Thanks to all for your responses.  All are good and worthy of being accepted as the answer, but Eru Penkman's answer is the closed to the context I'm going to be using, so I'm marking this as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you're after [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/5FG8C/3/) you were absoloutely correct about needing float left on the last element, it should be wrapped with the other element that it is to align with

```
    <select class="selector">
        <option>One</option>
    </select>
    <div class="right-side">
        <select class="selector">
            <option>Two</option>
        </select>
        <select class="selector">
            <option>Three</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

css:

```
.right-side {
    float: left; 
    width: 60%;
}

.selector {
    width: 150px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

hey i think this should work for you.. 
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/W2GmU/1/)
http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/W2GmU/1/

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <select class="selector">
        <option>One</option>
    </select>
    <select class="selector">
        <option>Two</option>
    </select>
    <select class="selector thirdSlector">
        <option>Three</option>
    </select>
</div>


<style>

.wrapper {  width: 900px}
select { float: left; }
.selector { width: 150px; margin-left: 5px;}
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) { 
    .wrapper {
        width:310px;
        border : 1px solid #900;
        display:inline-block;
    }
    .thirdSlector {
        float: right !important; 
    }
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this: wrapper = 465 (3 x 155) normally, then use a media selector when it's below that to force it down to only fit two across (310), like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/FXN7Z/

```
.wrapper {
    max-width: 465px;
}

.selector {
    width: 150px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.float-left {
    float: left;
}

.float-right {
    float: right;
}

@media (max-width: 465px) {
    .wrapper {
        width: 310px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like you said, you were very close already, I have updated your code a little bit, see [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Godinall/Fpsn7/2/)
Just add below code:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
    .selector:last-child{
        margin-left:160px;
    }
}
```